# is there a trim() function for RDDs?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

To remove leading and trailing whitespaces, I know you can use trim on dataframes. Is there a similar function when using RDDs? If not, how would you do this?

---

Edit: Added some code:

```
nonNullRDD = marchRDD.filter(lambda row: row.title).filter(lambda row: row.authors)
titleRDD = nonNullRDD.map(lambda field: (field.title, field.authors))
splitRDD = titleRDD.flatMap(lambda field: [(field[0], z) for z in field[1].split(";")])
authorRDD = splitRDD.map(lambda field: [field[1], 1])
test = authorRDD.flatMap(lambda word: word.strip())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDD's don't have string functions

I believe you're looking for Python `str.strip()`

```
trimmed_words = words.map(lambda word: word.strip())
```

Comment: This is giving a "list object has no attribute strip" error. I've added my code to the original question. I understand it's because I've created a list in all of the mappings, but how would I remedy this?

Comment: You'd need to know what type of object the RDD contains. My answer assumes you have an RDD of strings, not lists. Note that the lambda of your authorRDD has a 1 for some reason... You could simply strip the data in the titleRDD

Comment: I figured it out. I had kept the title and the author columns, which I believe made it into a list. I removed it and just kept the author column and then split and stripped, which worked. There is a 1 because after stripping, I used reduceByKey to count the occurrences of each. Thank you for your help.